# store async function into array and build some sort of queue to execute each in a row

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to build some sort of queue to avoid an api rate limit.

What I am doing is this (pseudo code) which for some reason is not working. They all get executed at the same time still. What am I missing?

```js
let queue = Promise<any>[] = [];

async function testFunction(params){
  console.log("im doing something blabla");
}


loopFunction(){
  queue.push(testFunction("sdsds");
  queue.push(testFunction("sdsds");
  queue.push(testFunction("sdsds");
  queue.push(testFunction("sdsds");
}


async startApp(){
  setInterval(()=>{
    //take first 3 items and execute the functions
    let tasks = queue.splice(0,3);
    
    for(t in tasks) {
      tasks[t];
    }
  },250);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using rsjx for production code (don't reinvent wheel).

Comment: Your queue should be an array of functions (or an array of objects with properties for the function to call and the argument[s] to pass it), not an array of promises. When you call an `async` function, you start its work. It doesn't start *later* when you use the returned promise. Promises don't *do* anything, they just provide a standardized way to get notified of the completion of something that's *already running*.

Comment: so instead of promise any type, It needs to be some sort of function array type?

Comment: Right, or (again) an array of objects with a property for the function to call and a property for the argument(s) to pass it.

Comment: could you tell me what I have to add as a type? I searched and could not find any type for array of async functions.